# Maximum kbps for AAC audio stream (MPEG-2/4)

Tags: audio, codec, iso, aac, mpeg-4

What are the absolute maximum bitrate the standardized MPEG-2 Part 7 AAC (ISO/IEC 13818-7:1997) and MPEG-4 Audio AAC (ISO/IEC 14496-3:1999) can output by the specifications?